# Optimization on large tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query that joins two large tables. I am trying to join on patient_id and records that are not older than 30 days.

```
select * from 
chairs c
join data id
   on c.patient_id = id.patient_id
   and to_date(c.from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') - to_date(id.from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') >= 0
   and to_date (c.from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') - to_date(id.from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') < 30
```

Currently, this query takes 2 hours to run. What indexes can I create on these tables for this query to run faster.

Comment: These dates are stored as text strings? Why?

Comment: Please post a query plan. You should also see if you can think of a way to perform that date calculation without transforming the fields, which I'm sure is possible.

Comment: whats datatype of "from_date" on both tables? also provide result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)`

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations if you are stuck with string fields for the dates:

1. YYYYMMDD date strings are ordered and can be used for <,> and =.
2. Building strings from the data in chairs to use to JOIN on data will make good use of an index like one on data for patient_id, from_date.

So my suggestion would be to write expressions that build the date strings you want to use in the JOIN. Or to put it another way: do not transform the child table data from a string to something else.

Example expression that takes 30 days off a string date and returns a string date:

```
select to_char(to_date('20200112', 'YYYYMMDD') - INTERVAL '30 DAYS','YYYYMMDD')
```

Untested:

```
select * from 
chairs c
join data id
   on c.patient_id = id.patient_id
   and id.from_date between to_char(to_date(c.from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') - INTERVAL '30 DAYS','YYYYMMDD')
                   and c.from_date
```

Answer (score 0):

I will take a shot in the dark, because as others said it depends on what the table structure, indices, and the output of the planner is.

The most obvious thing here is that as long as it is possible, you want to represent dates as some date datatype instead of strings. That is the first and most important change you should make here. No index can save you if you transform strings. Because very likely, the problem is not the patient_id, it's your date calculation.

Other than that, forcing hash joins on the patient_id and then doing the filtering could help if for some reason the planner decided to do nested loops for that condition. But that is for after you fixed your date representation AND you still have a problem AND you see that the planner does nested loops on that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select *
from chairs c join data
     id
     on c.patient_id = id.patient_id and
        to_date(c.from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') - to_date(id.from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') >= 0 and
        to_date (c.from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') - to_date(id.from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') < 30;
```

You should start with indexes on `(patient_id, from_date)` -- you can put them in both tables.

The date comparisons are problematic.  Storing the values as actual dates can help.  But it is not a 100% solution because comparison operations are still needed.

Depending on what you are actually trying to accomplish there might be other ways of writing the query.  I might encourage you to ask a *new* question, providing sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you really want.  For instance, this query is likely to return a lot of rows.  And that just takes time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your query have a non SERGABLE predicate because it uses functions that are iteratively executed. You need to discard such functions and replace them by a direct access to the columns. As an exemple :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   chairs AS c
       JOIN data AS id
          ON c.patient_id = id.patient_id
             AND c.from_date BETWEEN id.from_date AND id.from_date + INTERVAL '1 day'
```

Will run faster with those two indexes :

```
CREATE X_SQLpro_001 ON chairs (patient_id, from_date); 
CREATE X_SQLpro_002 ON data   (patient_id, from_date) ;
```

Also try to avoid

```
SELECT *
```

And list only the necessary columns